# How to see if a data in SQL Server starts with an integer using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET and SQL Server for a project. I want to check if the username of a user starts with an integer (username is in the database). So if the username is 123jas, the user will be redirected to `page.aspx`, but if it is jas123, user will be directed to `page2.aspx`.

I'm fairly new to this so sorry if the question does not make sense.

Do tell if you need the code that I have until now, which is just the login part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.7.2) can help you:

```
var redirectTo = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && char.IsDigit(userName[0]) ? "page1" : "page2";
```

Comment: `userName.ToCharArray()[0]` do you really want to convert the whole string to array if you just want to access the first character? `userName[0]`

Comment: Good catch @fubo, changed

Comment: @hardkoded It's not changed buddy. `char.IsDigit(userName.ToCharArray()[0])` should become `char.IsDigit(userName[0])`. Correct answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Adriani6 I missed that, changed. Thanks!

Comment: This helped! Thank you so much!